# cjson.decode() of a multi layer JSON

Tags: lua, nodemcu, cjson

I want to decode a multi layered json object into a table and print the value of "temp".

```Lua
p=666
d=23.42
payload='{"d":
             {"pres":'..(p)..',"temp":'..(d)..'}
         }'

t = cjson.decode(payload)
```

My first idea was something like this:

```Lua
print(t["d"]["temp"])
```

But this did not work. How can I improve this code so that it correctly decodes using Lua-CJson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have line breaks in quoted strings.

There are two solutions:

- remove the line breaks from `'...'`.

  `payload='{"d": {"pres":'..(p)..',"temp":'..(d)..'} }'`
- use the long string form: `[[ ... ]`, which allows line breaks.

  `payload=[[{"d":
               {"pres":]]..(p)..',"temp":'..(d)..[[}
           }]]`

You may also use a template, which makes things clearer:

```
p=666
d=23.42
payload=[[
    { "d":
            {"pres": (p), "temp": (d)}
    }'
]]  
payload=payload:gsub("%((.-)%)",_G)
print(payload)
```

If your fields are not global variables, put them in a table and use that table instead of `_G`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the linebreak. But my main problem was that I have a multi layered json object that is parsed into a lua table with cjson.decode.
This lua table acts like an array but I can only access key:value pairs from the first layer with something like this:  print(t["d"])  
but I want to access the value "temp" in the second layer but found no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting Json directly does not seem to work with cJson ( atleast not on the ESP8266 with NodeMCU ) I found a solution by wrapping an array around the nested values.

```
p = 666
d = "23.42"
payload='{"d":[{"pres":'..(p)..',"temp":"'..(d)..'"}]}'
t = cjson.decode(payload)
print(t.d[1].temp) -- prints "23.42"
```

**# Note 1** - this means you have to address the array before calling the variable **t.d[1]** - Arrays in Lua begin with the number **1** and are **NOT** zero-based like many other scripting languages.

**# Note 2** - for some reason I got a 'Malformed number' error with the floating point value ( variable d ). As a string the value is decoded without error. I had to make the variable a string and put "double quotation marks" around the value. 
--> ah I found out I was working on a integer version of nodeMCU - which apparently does not support floating point numbers ...